# can't match route with named parameters in finatra controller

Tags: scala, finatra, httprouter

I am using `com.twitter.finatra.http.Controller` to set up endpoints in Scala and I have an endpoint like this:

```
get(s"${endpoint}/:id/lookup/?") {request: Request => 
 println("here")
 val id = request.params("id")
 response.ok
}
```

It is my understanding that it should match the link `http://myservice/123/lookup` and `request.params("id")` should return "123". But it never gets to println. However when I try `http://myservice/:id/lookup` (exactly like that) - it does. So it's expecting exactly ":id" in the address rather than a dynamic value. And obviously `request.params("id")` is not there. If I call  `http://myservice/:id/lookup?id=123`, then `request.params("id")` is `123` coming from the query string parameter

What am doing wrong or misunderstanding? I am very new to Scala, so it's entirely possible that the whole thing is set up not how it is supposed to.